# javascript push multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I've got something like that:

```
    var valueToPush = new Array();
    valueToPush["productID"] = productID;
    valueToPush["itemColorTitle"] = itemColorTitle;
    valueToPush["itemColorPath"] = itemColorPath;

    cookie_value_add.push(valueToPush);
```

the result is [];

what am i do wrong?

Comment: Where did you see "the result is []"?

Comment: If you want to create an array use [] literal notation instead of new Array. Also, if you want to store general key-value pairs use normal objects instead of arrays: `var toPush = {}; toPush.productId = ...`

Comment: the result was in my cookie i stored the value into, and with more values storing, more [] appeared...

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Arrays must have zero based integer indexes in JavaScript. So:

```
var valueToPush = new Array();
valueToPush[0] = productID;
valueToPush[1] = itemColorTitle;
valueToPush[2] = itemColorPath;
cookie_value_add.push(valueToPush);
```

Or maybe you want to use objects (which are associative arrays):

```
var valueToPush = { }; // or "var valueToPush = new Object();" which is the same
valueToPush["productID"] = productID;
valueToPush["itemColorTitle"] = itemColorTitle;
valueToPush["itemColorPath"] = itemColorPath;
cookie_value_add.push(valueToPush);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
var valueToPush = { };
valueToPush.productID = productID;
valueToPush.itemColorTitle = itemColorTitle;
valueToPush.itemColorPath = itemColorPath;
cookie_value_add.push(valueToPush);
```

It's a really fundamental and crucial difference between JavaScript arrays and JavaScript objects (which are associative arrays) that every JavaScript developer must understand.

Comment: Arrays are objects too. Therefore, in the original code the properties are there, and it's not just `[]`.

Comment: @Y. Shoham, yes arrays are objects. It's just that the `[]` property has a special meaning for them. You can only use 0 based integers which is at the root of the OPs problem.

Answer (score 15):

Use **`[]`**:

```
cookie_value_add.push([productID,itemColorTitle, itemColorPath]);
```

or

```
arrayToPush.push([value1, value2, ..., valueN]);
```

Answer (score 5):

In JavaScript, the type of key/value store you are attempting to use is an object literal, rather than an array. You are mistakenly creating a composite array object, which happens to have other properties based on the key names you provided, but the array portion contains no elements.

Instead, declare `valueToPush` as an object and push that onto `cookie_value_add`:

```
// Create valueToPush as an object {} rather than an array []
var valueToPush = {};

// Add the properties to your object
// Note, you could also use the valueToPush["productID"] syntax you had
// above, but this is a more object-like syntax
valueToPush.productID = productID;
valueToPush.itemColorTitle = itemColorTitle;
valueToPush.itemColorPath = itemColorPath;

cookie_value_add.push(valueToPush);

// View the structure of cookie_value_add
console.dir(cookie_value_add);
```