# Accessing nested array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I wrote some code where data is going into an array. At each index, I have another array that has an array with five data elements. What I want to do is to add data at the end of each nested array.

```
var allTimeStamps = [];
var allTimeStampsData = [];
$.getJSON( "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo", function( data ) {

    const responseData = data;

    for(let key in responseData["Time Series (Daily)"]){
        allTimeStamps.push(key);
        allTimeStamps.push(parseFloat((responseData["Time Series (Daily)"][key]["3. low"])));
        allTimeStamps.push(parseFloat(responseData["Time Series (Daily)"][key]["1. open"]));
        allTimeStamps.push(parseFloat(responseData["Time Series (Daily)"][key]["4. close"]));
        allTimeStamps.push(parseFloat(responseData["Time Series (Daily)"][key]["2. high"]));
        allTimeStampsData.push(allTimeStamps);
        allTimeStamps=[];
    }
    console.log("seperatedData", allTimeStampsData);                
});
```

I am trying something like this:

**Old**

```
allTimeStampsData[0].append("121");
```

**New**

```
allTimeStampsData[0].push("121");
```

I wrote append because of Python. I was actually trying to push, but this is not working.

I am expecting output like:

```
[ ["08-2-2018",98,12,98,78,121] ,......]
```

Comment: `allTimeStampsData[0].push("121");` ?!

Comment: Perhaps an example of the array you receive would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do something like this is with a simple `.map` over the entries of the `"Time Series (Daily)"` property, from which you can extract the date and the low/open/close/high:

```js
fetch("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(responseData => {
    const daily = responseData["Time Series (Daily)"];
    const keys = [
      '3. low',
      '1. open',
      '4. close',
      '2. high',
    ];
    const allTimeStampsData = Object.entries(daily)
      .map(([date, infoObj]) => (
        [date, ...keys.map(key => infoObj[key])]
      ));
    console.log(allTimeStampsData[0]);
    console.log(allTimeStampsData);
  });
```

Comment: Bonus promisification! Nice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the `push` method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Initialize your array
`var my_arr = ['Volvo', 'Ford', 'Chevrolet'];`

Then use the `push` method to add a new value to it.

`my_arr.push('Mercedes');`

Now `my_arr = ['Volvo', 'Ford', 'Chevrolet', 'Mercedes'];`

Comment: basically what i want to access the elements of nested array. this have nothing to do with nested array

Comment: @tadman when I answered the question he had it set to `append`, not `push`.

Comment: Ah, on that one line. The rest of the question already had `push` in it though.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly assign the field in your `allTimeStampsData` array:

```
allTimeStampsData[allTimeStampsData.length] = allTimeStamps;
```

Thereafter, `allTimeStampsData[i].push("121");` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the original question needs to be clarified here folks. As [@josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10044014/josh-darby) mentioned that you use `$.push()` to append data to the end of an array. Regardless of how many levels deep the Array is using `.push()` is the best way to add data to an array. Also this sounds like a duplicate question which is posted here [javascript-push-multidimensional-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880257/javascript-push-multidimensional-array)

Comment: This feels more like a comment rather than an answer that will be useful now or in the future. If this is a duplicate, just flag or comment as such and mods will usually pick that thread up.